# Declining post-internship offer when I already have another full time offer

Tags: united-states, internship, job-change

I am graduating college soon, and have interned at a company (Company A) for multiple years. Aside from this company I have interned at one other. I don't particularly mind working here, but it certainly isn't my ideal job.

Since I first came to university, I became really interested with certain company (Company B),  so much that I took classes for that they specifically recommended/required in order to possibly get a job there one day. This company has a reputation on my campus as hiring very rarely, and are looked upon as a great company to work for.

Now, I had accepted my current company's offer of a summer internship as of last September, so that was locked in a while ago. I also managed to successfully get/pass the interview and obtain a full-time offer from Company B earlier this year, while letting them know about my internship with Company A.

I know that they pay much higher than the market rate in my area, while Company A pays slightly below. Also, the work would be **significantly** more interesting and greatly in my interests. With this knowledge, I accepted the offer from Company B to start full time after I graduate.

Now, my problem: Company A is going to want me to reapply for a full time offer, and as far as I can tell, I have a few options:

- Reapply and decline the offer.
- Tell my recruiter preemptively to avoid wasting his (and my) time.

I do feel bad, since my recruiter has really went above and beyond for me, and helped me personally with some issues outside my internship (related to work).

It's undeniable that I plan to work for Company B. However, a big part of this question is, when asked, how do I talk about it? Do I feign ignorance, or should I tell my recruiter and team?

What should I do?

Comment: I'm sorry, a little new to (posting to) the site. To clarify, they want me to reapply at the end of the summer, to work after I graduate.

Comment: Hey aquastan, don't worry, welcome to The Workplace. The good thing is that any user may suggest and edit your post to improve it, so no worries if it's not perfect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have already accepted the offer from Company B for full time after you graduate, *don't bother with reapplying.*  Don't feel bad about going to another company, its normal that people leave to focus on career advancement.

Personally, and if the recruiter is going to automatically reapply you for the job, I would let them know ahead of time just so that you don't waste their time.  If they extend an offer to you while you are still working there, just decline and thank them.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you have lined up an internship with Company A and a job with Company B. Company B is cool with the internship. Company A are likely to ask you to apply for a full time job.

You want to work for Company B and not Company A, but Company A would also like you to work for them.

My advice: Work for Company B. It's where your passion lies, it sounds like it's a rare opportunity, and the pay is better. The downside is you will mildly inconvenience Company A, which might make it tricky to go back in the future, but honestly, if they pay low and you're not that interested, should that really be an issue?

It reflects well on your personality that you feel bad for inconveniencing the recruiter, but you won't be the first one, or the last. Do let them know as soon as you've made up your mind though.

When it comes to this sort of thing, you have to think about what **you** want most. If you join Company A out of guilt, you'll regret your choice of not joining Company B and will more than likely grow to resent your job, at which point you'll probably end up quitting anyway!

Answer (score 2):

> What should I do?

Seems you already made up your mind for Company B.

If Company A eventually offers you a full-time offer, then you should *decline and thank them for their offer.* No need to give big explanations, if any just say you want to explore new options now you finished your studies, and that you are really thankful for everything they did for you.

You are graduating and about to start a new journey on your professional career, so don't hold back to a great opportunity just because something "will be expected from you".

**Declining their offer is a *professional choice*, no one has any reasons to expect you do decide the way they want, nor any reasons to take it personal if you don't.** It's your career after all.